# Name of state variables in React hooks

Tags: reactjs

This may be a really dumb question, but I don´t understand how this example from the React Hooks tutorial works:

```
function FriendStatus(props) {
  const [isOnline, setIsOnline] = useState(null);

  function handleStatusChange(status) {
    setIsOnline(status.isOnline);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    ChatAPI.subscribeToFriendStatus(props.friend.id, handleStatusChange);
    return () => {
      ChatAPI.unsubscribeFromFriendStatus(props.friend.id, handleStatusChange);
    };
  });

  if (isOnline === null) {
    return 'Loading...';
  }
  return isOnline ? 'Online' : 'Offline';
}
```

Shouldn´t the argument used by setIsOnline inside handleStatus be named isOnline instead of status.isOnline since isOnline is a part of state (and there´s no such thing as status.isOnline inside state)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`handleStatusChange` is a function passed to the chat api:

```
 ChatAPI.subscribeToFriendStatus(props.friend.id, handleStatusChange);
```

The `ChatAPI`, internally, will call that function with the `status` argument.  The format of the `status` object is defined by `ChatApi`.

The handler is responding to the event:

```
  function handleStatusChange(status) {
    setIsOnline(status.isOnline);
  }
```

And sets the value of `status.isOnline` from `ChatAPI` to be the new value of `isOnline`.

Answer (score 0):

Correct there is no status.isOnline inside the state. But when handleStatusChange is called you pass in the status from the API, which would return in the JSON object a boolean that is called isOnline. That's where the status.isOnline comes from.

It looks like a fake API they used to show off the Hooks functionality. The response would have something like this I assume:

```
status: {
  isOnline: true,
  chatData: {},
  otherData: {},
}
```